# access configuration/property files from src/groovy

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have a file under src/groovy and I have some properties that are in my Config.groovy and in external property file too. Normally if one want access properties its possible to use grailsApplication .configuration.property.name expression. I want to be able to access all those properties from this file that is under src/groovy directory. What I've tried so far

```
import grails.util.Holders

class ForkedTomcatCustomizer {

    def application

    void customize(Tomcat tomcat) {

        println Holders.grailsApplication.config.property.name
    }
}
```

gave me NPE saying that grailsAppliction is null

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes as GA



class ForkedTomcatCustomizer {

    def application

    void customize(Tomcat tomcat) {

        def ctx = SCH.servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
        def grailsAppliction = ctx.grailsApplication.getObject()
        println grailsAppliction.config.property.name
    }
}
```

the same - NPE because grailsAppliction is null

Is it possible to handle this situation somehow? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below and see if it works

```
println Holders.config.property.name
```

You don't need grailsApplication when using Holders.

Comment: Unfortunately this give NPE as well. Saying that config object is null

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky - That's strange!! I have been using this all over my src files and it works perfectly for me. I am using grails 2.1.2, Not sure but it might be some related to the version

Comment: My guess is that he's trying to access the config before it has been constructed, e.g. during build-time

Comment: @LalitAgarwal I'm using different one - 2.4.2

Comment: @Dónal yes, seems like, is it possible to force loading of configurtion from within this class?

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky - If you have the location of the file then probably you could just read the file here directly.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal the funny thing is that there is a path in this property :-) I mean I'm trying to achieve full independence from hardcoded paths

Answer (score 0):

The examples below are probably a little more complex than what you need, but they show how to get a configuration property at build time. I use them to merge two configuration files, but you might not need to do that.

This [method](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-angularjs/blob/master/src/groovy/org/grails/plugins/angularjs/AngularjsConfigurationHolder.groovy#L14) returns a config property when called [here](https://github.com/kensiprell/grails-angularjs/blob/master/scripts/_Events.groovy#L13) at the CompileEnd event.

You could define a similar method in your app's _Events.groovy file that calls your own configuration holder class.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder;

class KeyAndSecret{
     public static String consumerKey = ConfigurationHolder.config.consumerKey;
     public static String consumerSecret = ConfigurationHolder.config.consumerSecret;
}
```

Try like this